# Jersey JAX-RS annotating interface not the implementation class results in error

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I got an interface annotated with JAX-RS annotations. 
In the implementation class itself I just override the methods of the interface; not overriding annotations or anything.

I get the following error:
**The class {name} is an interface and cannot be instantiated.**

I've tried making a jar of my annotated interface and put it in .war \lib folder, yet the error persists.

If it matters, I'm using JBoss's embedded Tomcat.

Here's the interface:

```
  @javax.ws.rs.Path( "/jerseytesting.HelloWorldService" )
  public interface HelloWorldService {
    @javax.ws.rs.POST
    @javax.ws.rs.Path( "/Greet" )
    @javax.ws.rs.Consumes({"application/protobuf", "application/json"})
    @javax.ws.rs.Produces({"application/protobuf", "application/json"})
    jerseytesting.Twirpproto.HelloResponse greet(jerseytesting.Twirpproto.HelloRequest request);
  }
```

And here is the implementation:

```
public class Twirpy implements Twirpproto.HelloWorldService {

    @Override
    public HelloResponse greet(HelloRequest request) {
        HelloResponse helloResponse = HelloResponse.newBuilder().setResponse("Hello, " + request.getName()).build();
        return helloResponse;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste the respective code in the question

Comment: and the actual error message/stack trace please? (not dummy one)

Answer (score 3):

From the API documentation:

> JAX-RS annotations MAY be used on the methods and method parameters of
>   a super-class or an implemented interface.

So, only the method annotations can be on the interface.

The concrete class should have the `@Path`. Only then JAX-RS will know to create an instance of that concrete class.

Like so:

```
@javax.ws.rs.Path( "/jerseytesting.HelloWorldService" )
public class Twirpy implements Twirpproto.HelloWorldService {

    @Override
    public HelloResponse greet(HelloRequest request) {
        HelloResponse helloResponse = HelloResponse.newBuilder().setResponse("Hello, " + request.getName()).build();
        return helloResponse;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's interesting... Because the interface is an autogenerated code by a RPC framework.

Comment: Yea, I can confirm that the Path annotation must go on the concrete class for the server to discover it. The annotation on the interface is useful when you are using the [proxy client](https://allegro.tech/2015/05/JAX-RS-client-api.html), in which case, the Path would be used to make outbound calls.

Comment: Thank you all. The annotated interface generator I was using was expecting me to use RestEasy JAX-RS implementation, which allows for annotated interfaces. I was using Jersey myself for JAX-RS implementation, which doesn't allow for annotated interfaces, just as you noted.